# Decode JSON object with array and not a dictionary

Tags: json, swift, api

I'm using an API that returns a JSON object in the following format:

```
{
    "cards": [
        {
            "name": "Charizard"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

When I try to decode this, it says it it's not valid JSON... it says it expected an array but got a dictionary. I have a feeling it's because I not actually selecting the cards array from the object? But I can't figure out how to modify my snippet to achieve it...

```
import SwiftUI

struct Card: Codable {
    var name: String
}

class Api {
    func getCards(completion: @escaping ([Card]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.pokemontcg.io/v1/cards") else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            let cards = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Card].self, from: data!)
    
            print(cards)
            
            //DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //    completion(cards)
            //}
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to decode the top level JSON object.

You can  either create another struct like this:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var cards: [Card]
}
```

and use the following code to decode your JSON:

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data!)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

or you can use `[String: [Card]]` as decoding type:

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: [Card]].self, from: data!)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Either way, never use `try!`. It is always better to `do-catch` and print the error that you might get.

Answer (score 0):

So what you're trying to decode is not actually an array of `Card`, but an object which has a property `cards` which is an array of `Card`. So try creating a struct for the container and decoding that.

```
struct CardResponse: Codable {
    let cards: [Card]
}
```